# Dealing random poker hands

Tags: java

in my program im able to deal 5 random cards to players but i was wondering how can i incorporate a deck shuffle in my program because in my way of randomizing i tend to end up with repeated cards

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog2d {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userChoice;
        String[] suit = {"Clubs","Diamonds","Hearts","Spades"};
        String[] faces = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","King","Queen","Ace"};
        String[][] deck = new String[faces.length][suit.length];


        System.out.println("Program 2d, Christian Villa, masc1854");

        userChoice = in.nextInt();

        while(userChoice > 0)
        {


           for(int k = 0; k < 5;k++)
                {
                   int i = (int)(Math.random()*suit.length);
                   int j = (int)(Math.random()*faces.length);

                   System.out.println(faces[j] + " of " + suit[i]);
                }
                 userChoice--;
               System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle using the `Collections.shuffle` the array first and then iterate without using the `Math.random` method:

```
while(userChoice > 0)
    {

       Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(suit));
       Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(faces));
       for(int k = 0; k > 4;k++)
            {
               System.out.println(faces[k] + " of " + suit[k]);
            }
             userChoice--;
           System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: hmm now it just terminates as soon as i enter the users choice